# get last inserted primary key of type varchar in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have two table **userGold** and **AspNetUserRoles(UserId,RoleId)** .
primary key type of UserGold is **nvarchar(450)**
same for AspNetUserRole.
my problem is that i want to get the last inserted primary key in UsereGold and insert it in AspNetUserRoles table using a trigger.
SCOPE_IDENTITY didn't work cause my primary key type is **nvarchar**.
i don't know what to do.
i saw solution **like output inserted** but it didn't work

```
create trigger addrole
on UserGold
after Insert
as
Begin
declare 
@userid nvarchar(450)
set @userid=CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS nvarchar(450))
insert into AspNetUserRoles(UserId,RoleId) 
values(@userid,'2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe')
end
```

Comment: Does this helps? `SET NOCOUNT ON;` and `SELECT INSERTED.UserId AS userGoldUserId
      FROM INSERTED` inside your trigger?

Comment: should i replace @userid in the insert  values(@userid,...)with userGoldUserId ?

Comment: `insert into AspNetUserRoles(UserId,RoleId) 
SELECT INSERTED.userId as UserId,'2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe' as RoleId from INSERTED`

Answer (score 0):

You should not write triggers - or anything else in a database - that only expect a single row to change. Databases work with sets of information, not single "records". Imagine what happens if someone create 5 rows in UserGold in a single insert statement. You can't put 5 userid values into a single @userId variable.

What you want is something like

```
-- assuming your tables are in the dbo schema! Make sure you include the schema name
create trigger AddDefaultRole on dbo.UserGold after insert as begin
   set nocount on;
   insert dbo.AspNetUserRoles (UserId, RoleId) 
   select UserId, '2c258e8d-c648-4b38-9b01-989d4dd525fe' 
   from   inserted;
end
```

For more information, see [Inserted and Deleted tables for triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)